# Jquery UI Autocomplete This not working to pass id as separate parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

So I am trying to pass another parameter "field" which will let me grab the id of the input that is being typed in. This would allow me to direct the PHP to make the proper SQL statement to the database as i will have multiple inputs on a page that need autocomplete to work. I know that below is missing the response and that is because i wasn't exactly sure what to put. I just want to return the json string like normal. How can i get the id to be passed as well as what do i put for the response?

```
('.completeme').autocomplete({    
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/ajax_diagnosis.php",
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term,
                        field: $(this).attr("id"),
                        maxRows: 15                     
                }
            },

            minLength: 3,
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$(this.element).attr("id")
```

This could be the final script:

```
$(function() {
        var cache = {},
            lastXhr={};
        $( ".completeme" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: function( request, response ) {

                    var term = request.term,
                        field=$(this.element).attr('id');
                    if(!field)return;
                    if ( cache[field] && term in cache[field] ) {
                        response( cache[field][ term ] );
                        return;
                    }

                $.extend(request,{field:field,maxRows:15});
                lastXhr[field] = $.getJSON( "ajax/ajax_diagnosis.php", 
                                    request, 
                                    function( data, status, xhr ) {
                                    if(!cache[field])cache[field]={};
                                              cache[field][ term ] = data;
                                              if ( xhr === lastXhr[field] ) {
                                                response( data );
                                             }
                                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I can see that this indeed did pass the id (looked inside firebug to see the request that was sent) however I am still not sure how to do the success argument correctly. I've been trying for quite a few hours now to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Incredible. This works perfectly... If only I had a clue as to what each line did...